# Hover function using HTML and CSS on Squarespace

Tags: html, css, hover, squarespace

*note: Sorry guys, I'm absolutely new to this. Thank you for letting me know what you find are the mistakes on this post. I'll try to do better next time. :)*

I'm having a problem with a hover effect I made for a design client on Squarespace. ***(I don't know how to code, lol)***

What I'm trying to do is when a user hovers over an image, the image gets darker and a text block appears.
I was able to make it work but somehow it only works when one hovers on top and it doesn't function otherwise.

[Here's a recording](https://www.loom.com/share/f3968441ab5d445e9ddd6e53b4b3e18b)

In squarespace: I added an image block, and the HTML code block with the text over it.

Please can anybody check how to fix this? I appreciate any help! TIA

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #101440;
  opacity: 80%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img-container:hover .overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/63b5…516bb941/shutterstock_1603765507.jpg?format=1000w
" alt="">
  <div class="overlay">
    <p style="font-size: 0.8em; padding: 0 20px;">text goes here</p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image used in your example doesn't load for me, and when I replace it with a working one, your snippet does not appear to actually reproduce the problem. Questions like this need a proper [mre].

Comment: Protip: ChatGPT is not ready to be your virtual developer. Don't use it, and don't distract by posting its garble in your questions here. :)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for help using this site.

Answer (score 0):

To sum this method up:
Create a DIV that wraps around your imagery and the text (and get the DIV to be directly on top of it all).
Then ( in our case) we made the text an instant hover color change (darkened via opacity), and the image on a delayed transition (using filter).
The entire key to this puzzle is causing pre-hover to initially be *invisible*, then upon hover the opacity of the text activates instantly, while  0.5seconds later the image darkens.
So...the 'hoverMe' DIV is the solution solved by wrapping **BOTH** the image and text.
I opted to set the text backdrop tone darker and the image overlay slightly lighter, which added an additional minor step to the CSS.
Here's an example solution:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box;}

.container {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: min(calc(100% - 1em), 22em);
  margin: auto;  /*--set image top center--*/
}

/*--Keep image stacked exactly on top--*/
.container img {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  width: 100%;}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.text-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.text-info {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

h3 {color:#ffff00;}

/* Hover protocol */
.text-info {visibility: hidden;}
.hoverMe:hover .text-info {opacity:1.0;}
.hoverMe:hover .text-info {visibility:visible;}
.hoverMe:hover img {filter: brightness(70%); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}

/*--Responsive--*/
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .text-info {
      font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + 1vmin);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hoverMe">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600.gif">
      <div class="text-frame">
        <div class="text-info">
          <h3>SCENE</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet an hia eti torquatos zxanlo arumit.</p>
        </div><!--close text-info-->
      </div><!--close text-frame-->
    </div><!--close content-->
  </div><!--close hover-->
</div><!--close container-->
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation at the top of your answer. Code dumps aren't considered valuable on SO. See [answer].